# Multiple Site Manager: how many subdomains?

Tags: multi-site-manager

According to addon description, there's a limit of 3 sites. Does sub.mainsite.com qualify as a separate "site"?

And if it does, is there a cheaper way to create unlimited subdomains of the same domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A subdomain would be a different site.

There is only a limit of 3 sites (whether run on subdomains or totally different domains) in as much as you can run 3 EE powered sites with the MSM licence and 1 installation of EE.

You can run more sites if you purchase more MSM site licences as a lower rate than regular EE licences.

MSM just makes it simpler to share templates and content across different sites and since they all run from a single EE installation it makes updates a lot easier too.

EllisLab will issue you with a couple of files which contain the encrypted licence keys for the sites you have. When you add sites it's a simple matter of replacing the file you have with the new one they send you.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on running each subdomain as a separate site within the EE CP then yes each subdomain will be one site. If you need additional sites for your MSM license you can purchase these for $49 per additional site. This option becomes available once you have an MSM license in your account.